# How to modify the array in a functional programming style?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

How to change the arr['first'] of each object in a functional programming style using forEach, map, reduce, filter etc.

```js
let value = 'abc'
let arr = [{
 'first': 'aaa' 
},{
 'first': 'bbb' 
},{
 'first': 'ccc' 
}];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: In a functional paradigm, you *wouldn't* be changing the array but making a copy. With that said, it also depends on what exactly you'd even want to do - if you want to only operate on the first element, you're most likely going to take that element and work with it, as opposed to operating on the array in order to do something only with the first element.

Comment: Change it *how*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` and create a  new array

```js
let value = 'abc';
let arr = [{
  'first': 'aaa'
}, {
  'first': 'bbb'
}, {
  'first': 'ccc'
}];

let newArr = arr.map(function(item) {

  return {
    first: value
  }

})

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an **immutable way** to update the property `first` of each item in your array. It uses [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array and the spread operator to copy each item and set the `first` property to `value`:

```js
const value = 'abc';

const arr = [{ 'first': 'aaa' },{ 'first': 'bbb' },{ 'first': 'ccc' }];

const newArr = arr.map(item => ({ ...item, first: value }));

console.log(newArr);
```

If you want to **mutate the original array**, which is not a good idea with the functional paradigm, use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead:

```js
const value = 'abc';

const arr = [{ 'first': 'aaa' },{ 'first': 'bbb' },{ 'first': 'ccc' }];

arr.forEach(item => item.first = value);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

if I good understand you, you want to change key name 'first' in every object of array using map?

you can try below code:

```
const value = 'abc';
const arr = [{
 'first': 'aaa' 
},{
 'first': 'bbb' 
},{
 'first': 'ccc' 
}];

const newArr = arr.map(obj => {
  if ('first' !== value) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, value,
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'first'));
    delete obj['first'];
  }
  return obj;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

or if you want to change only value of first in every obj:

```
const value = 'abc';
const arr = [{
 'first': 'aaa' 
},{
 'first': 'bbb' 
},{
 'first': 'ccc' 
}];

const newArr = arr.map(obj => ({...obj, first: value}));
console.log(newArr);
```